# Parameter estimation in the linear mixed effects model

Tags: mixed-model, variance, covariance, linear-algebra, blup

In [Parameter estimation and inference in the linear mixed effects model](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S002437951100320X), page 1923, the variance

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\text{var}(\tilde{u} - u) & = \sigma^2G - \text{var}(\tilde{u}) \\
 & = \text{var}(u) - \text{var}(\tilde{u}), 
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

where $\tilde{u} = GZ^\top H^{-1}(y - X\hat{\beta})$ is the best linear unbiased predictor (BLUP) for the random effects vector $u$, where $G$ and $H$ are covariance matrices, $Z$ is a design matrix, $y$ is a vector of observations, and $\hat{\beta}$ is the maximum likelihood (ML) estimate for $\beta$.

By definition,

\begin{equation}
\text{var}(\tilde{u} - u) = \text{var}(u) + \text{var}(\tilde{u}) - 2\text{cov}(\tilde{u}, u), 
\end{equation}

this must mean that $\text{cov}(\tilde{u}, u) = \text{var}(\tilde{u})$. How can one show that $\text{cov}(\tilde{u}, u) = \text{var}(\tilde{u})$?

Comment: I strongly doubt your reference makes such an invalid *general* assertion about variances: are you sure you transcribed it correctly?  Try as I might, I cannot find anything like it on p. 1923.

Comment: On page 1923 (part of Lemma 1) it is stated that $\text{var}(\tilde{u} - u) = \sigma^2G - \text{var}(\tilde{u})$, and $\text{var}(u) = \sigma^2G$ (see page 1922, Equation (6)).

Comment: That's crucial contextual information, because it completely changes what you are asking!

Comment: Okay yes, sorry. I have edited the question to add that piece of information.

Answer (score 2):

We have that
$$\mbox{cov}(u, \tilde u) = E \Bigl [ \bigl \{u - E(u) \bigr \} \, \bigl \{ \tilde u - E(\tilde u)\bigr \} \Bigr ].$$

But $E(\tilde u) = u$ and $E(u) = \tilde u$. Note that expectations are here taken with respect to the posterior of the random effects, not the prior. Hence,
$$\mbox{cov}(u, \tilde u) = E \Bigl [ \bigl \{\tilde u - E(\tilde u) \bigr \} \, \bigl \{ \tilde u - E(\tilde u)\bigr \} \Bigr ] = \mbox{var}(\tilde u).$$

Comment: Using $E[\tilde{u}] = u$ and $E[u] = \tilde{u}$, should you not obtain $cov(u, \tilde{u}) = E\Big[\{ E(\tilde{u}) - \tilde{u}\}\{\tilde{u} - E(\tilde{u})\}\Big]$?